# English equivalent of the figurative sense of the German word "Beißreflex" (bite reflex)

Tags: single-word-requests

The German word for *bite reflex*, *Beißreflex*, has an additional figurative sense. Let's say Herr Ausraster has a massive hatred for the Ecological Democratic Party. Every time he reads something on a news site about the party, be it totally trivial and/or inoffensive, he simply has to write rants about this party. Herr Ausraster has a *Beißreflex* regarding this party.

So I'd like to know whether there is a word that does not just mean hating sth./so., but "acting knee-jerk fashion" when confronted with that person/thing etc. For example "As to the Democrats/Republicans/Libertarian Party, Jules has an XY (*Beißreflex*) — every time he reads about them on the website of the Podunk Enquirer, he writes offensive rants resulting in the deletion of his posts."

Comment: Your term comes close - *knee-jerk reaction* is idiomatic in English, though not necessarily about wanting to settle scores.

Comment: Yep, "knee-jerk reaction" is probably a close match.  Refers to the lower-leg jerking outward when the doc taps your knee with that rubber hammer.

Comment: Also relevant is **Pavolian response**. In contrast to **knee-jerk reaction** it implies the behaviour is learned even though it becomes automatic.

Comment: @SteveLovell Don't you mean [_Pavlovian_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivan_Pavlov)? Or did some _Pavol_ also do research in this field?

Comment: Oops yes **Pavlovian response**, sorry. Thanks @oerkelens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Visceral**
>   adjective  vis·cer·al \ˈvi-sə-rəl, ˈvis-rəl\
>
> 2: not intellectual; instinctive, unreasoning.

"Herr Ausraster has a ***visceral response*** regarding this party."

I am not sure there is a single word in English, but I believe this is less idiomatic than "knee-jerk"